# How to draw a rectangle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawrect

I want to draw a filled rectangle in my viewContoller's view.
I wrote the code below in viewDidLoad. But there is no change.
What is wrong?

```
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
```

Comment: please note, for this **extremely old question**, I've put in the modern answer, 2018

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't do it in a viewController.
You need to extend your View and add the code under "drawRect:"

this will change the drawing logic of your view.

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{    
[super drawRect:rect];  
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
}
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer - though I would not ignore the CGRect parameter of drawRect....

Comment: Right, I guess a better solution is to first verify that the area that needs to be re-drawn is part of the rectangle, and only then do it.

Comment: What do you mean extend view?

Comment: Create a new class for your view extending UIView

Comment: No need to call super here; as it says in the Apple UIView class reference: "If you subclass UIView directly, your implementation of this method does not need to call super."

Answer (score 6):

## modern 2018 solution..

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let r = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 10, height: 10)

    UIColor.yellow.set()
    UIRectFill(r)
}
```

that's it.

Answer (score 4):

Just for clarity:

If You need to draw a rectangle which has the same fill and border color, then You can replace:

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

with:

```
 [[UIColor redColor] set];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't render directly in viewDidLoad; it's the views themselves that would have to run this in their drawRect method.

The easiest way to "draw" a rectangle is to place a UIView with a background color & border in your view. (You can set the border via the view's CALayer's methods. i.e. `myView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];`)