# What is the correct way to draw a filled rectangle in iOS 6?

Tags: ios

I am a bit confused between different version of iOS SDK and information on the net. So I am not sure how I am supposed to draw a filled rectangle in case of iOS 6 SDK. Can anyone guide me to find an answer?

Comment: Can you describe what makes you confused?

Comment: Any way that works is a correct way, checkout this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195095/how-to-draw-rectangle or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082699/drawing-a-rectangle-in-uiview

Comment: How u have drawn rect by using CGContext or using UIBezierPath?

Answer (score 5):

There are various ways. You could try something like:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    CGContextRef cont = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(cont, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(cont, CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0));
}
```